# html tags rendered for nested association doesn't get wrapped in field_with_errors div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.1.4, ruby:2.3.7

I have a nested form for a parent model and children model with a validation on the uniqueness of the label in the child model in scope of the parent one. The issue is when I submit the form with identical names in both forms non of them get wrapped in the field_with_errors class. I need the html tag to be wrapped in that class so I can subsequently render errors on the form using bootstrap 4 invalid-feedback and invalid css classes.

How can I render the form with the field_with_errors div wrapping the text_field for the dashboard_label?

The models are as follows:

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :study_media_files
end

class StudyMediaFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  validates :dashboard_label, uniqueness: { scope: :project } 
end
```

The controller code is as follows:

```rb
class DsasController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @project = Mrcore::Project.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @project = Mrcore::Project.find params[:id]
    if(@project.update project_params)
      redirect_to @project, notice: 'updated successfully'
    else
      render 'show'
    end
  end

  private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(study_media_files_attributes: %i[id dashboard_label show])
  end
end
```

The view:

```rb
<%= f.fields_for :study_media_files, @project.study_media_files.non_zero_duration do |media_form| %>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-4 small">
            <%= media_form.object.affdex_movie_id %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <%= media_form.text_field :dashboard_label, class: 'input-sm col-lg form-control', required: true %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 float-right">
            <%= media_form.check_box :show, { class: 'form-check-input ml-2' } %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It seems that for some reason the object's dashboard_label gets reset to its original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the view with the fields for function loads the data from the database, I guess and overrides the errors that are transient on the project object, using a condition in the view code as below solved the issue.

```rb
<%= f.fields_for :study_media_files do |media_form| %>
    <% if media_form.object.duration > 0 %>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-4 small">
                <%= media_form.object.affdex_movie_id %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <%= media_form.text_field :dashboard_label, class: 'input-sm col-lg form-control' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 float-right">
                <%= media_form.check_box :show, { class: 'form-check-input ml-2' } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Essentially moving the collection on the fields_for block to a condition inside the block.